# What fonts are good for unicode glyphs

Tags: fonts, unicode

So I was looking at [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) and realized that my fonts aren't covering a whole lot of the utf-8 unicode spectrum (as I get lots of squares). Does anyone know a font that will cover all of that post?

Comment: not an answer to exactly your Q, but I [noted](http://kv.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:Imz/%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_ALTLinux_Sisyphus) a utility to conveniently list the fonts (installed) that support the orthogrphy of a given language, eg `fc-list :lang=kv family`, and then one can query for the corresponding files, pkgs, URLs, so that one can help others needing the fonts.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to post an answer, but SIL fonts like Charis and Gentium have great Unicode coverage.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The hands-down most comprehensive coverage would be Roman Czyborra's [GNU Unicode Font](http://czyborra.com/unifont/) project. It is intended to collect a complete and free 8×16/16×16 pixel Unicode font. It currently covers 34,445 characters (out of ~40,000+ defined characters).

Most distributions have GNU Unifont in their repositories.

Ed Trager has written a [Unicode Font Guide For Free/Libre Open Source Operating Systems](http://www.unifont.org/fontguide/) which collates geographic coverage of fonts and their associated licensing. The guide was last updated in 2008.

Other fonts with good Unicode support include:

- [DejaVu](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/)
- [GNU FreeFont](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/), worth noting is that the Serif contains [the most glyphs in this family](https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/coverage.html): Serif 10537 / Sans 6272 / Mono 4178

Comment: Unicode 10 contains 136690 characters.

Answer (score 20):

I came across this in 2016.

A single TTF/OTF font is never going to cover all utf-8 characters. There is a hard limit of 65535 glyphs in a font, and over 1 million utf-8 glphys. You will need to use a font-family for this to work.

A good font-family is the noto font family:
https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: The main issue is browsers can use only one font - as far as I know - for displaying e.g. websites. But the reality is a bit worse - a lot of glyphs missing from most popular fonts. So at least if the 64k glyph is stuffed, it would be better than the current state.

Comment: @GaborGarami Agreed, but some font mechanisms (like fontconfig) will try to grab glyphs from alternative fonts, even if different from the main font.

Comment: @rbrito ohh, i didn't know that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Most browsers will fallback for individual glyphs too.

Comment: there's no UTF-8 character because UTF-8 is just an encoding for Unicode. And there are only 0x10FFFF Unicode code points, any UTF-8 sequence that encodes a code point larger than U+10FFFF is invalid. Even UTF-32 is also limited to 0x10FFFF. See [Why Unicode is restricted to 0x10FFFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351/995714)