# How to change bash console font to display UTF-8 characters

Tags: bash, unicode

I'm having some trouble with displaying UTF-8 characters correctly on bash. I was trying to extract some zipped files that contained accented characters in their names, and I was getting the invalid multibyte characters error. I created a `.bash_profile` with this:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LOCALE=UTF-8
```

This solved the extraction problem. But the console still doesn't show the accented characters correctly. Konqueror has no problem with the accented characters. What do I have to do?

Comment: What terminal are you running in? Do you mean the Linux console (i.e. outside X)?

Comment: I'm running it under X, with fluxbox, using tilda.

Comment: $ locale ```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL= ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gnu Unifont has the widest unicode support. See [What fonts are good for unicode glyphs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/what-fonts-are-good-for-unicode-glyphs).

Changing the console font (ie., outside X) can be done with the `setfont` command. Which takes the form: `setfont /path/to/font`, eg:

```
setfont /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/$font
```

There is more information on the Arch Wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Console_fonts

Once you have selected your preferred font, setting the console font permanently will depend on your distribution. For example, in Ubuntu/Debian, it is:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```