# Crossmark symbol (\u274c) doesn't work in debian 12

Tags: terminal, unicode

I have moved from Ubuntu 22.04 to Debian 12, I have a bash function that outputs crossmark if command failed and checkmark if command succeed. The checkmark works, but the crossmark doesn't.

[image]

Here is the output of `locale`:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

I'm using debian 12 and qterminal.

Comment: It probably depends on the Font you use for that terminal. Some will include it, others will not . try to display : https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt in it

Comment: @OlivierDulac Well I have tried switching up fonts (currently using monaco) to default one the terminal use, it still had trouble rendering this symbol. I also notices many symbol appear as boxes, but when I copy them to textbox in my browser, the symbol is displayed correctly.

Comment: maybe try the ones in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14028/27616 (and other answers below it)

Comment: After downloading that UTF-8-test.txt, I found many "replacement character" (diamond with question mark).

Comment: Then choose a better font. try the ones listed at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14028/27616

Answer (score 0):

This probably depends on the Font you use for the terminal you use.

Change it until you find one that seems to better "cover" all possible unicode characters. Some good fonts to try for linux terminals: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14028/27616

You can also try to display in that terminal the content of : [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt)  to do a quite thorough test of coverage